# Football Pool - odds of buying (2) squares where the numbers received are "boxed"

Tags: probability, statistics

There are 100 squares in a standard football pool..  with the heading on each side 0-9.  So in a standard 10 x 10 square football pool, I just bought (2) boxes and the numbers drawn for the (2) boxes were:

1st square:   7,4

2nd square:    4,7

So..  I have the numbers 4 and 7 "boxed" no matter which team ends up winning.   What are the odds of that?   Buying (2) football pool squares and getting the numbers drawn "boxed" like that for both teams ?    No matter which team is on top at the end, if the last digits of the final score are either 7,4 or 4,7 then we win.   Curious about the statistics because this has never happened before.

Another way to ask the same question would be:

What are the odds, when buying (2) squares in a standard football pool, of having the numbers drawn "reversed"? or "boxed"?     i.e.

1st square:  7, 4

2nd square:  4, 7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no box is allocated more than once:

- You want your first box $x,y$ to have distinct values $y\not =x$.  The probability of that happening is $\dfrac{90}{100}=\dfrac{9}{10}$
- Given that, you want your second box to be the reverse of your first box, i.e.  $y,x$.  The conditional probability of that happening is $\dfrac{1}{99}$ as it is impossible to get your first box again and the others are equally likely

So the overall probability of getting this pattern is the product of these,  which is $\dfrac{1}{110}$